# Obtaining recurrence relation from polynomial

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations

Consider

> $P(n)=(\frac{1}{3})^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

From this, we can obtain the recurrence relation

> $P(n)=\frac{10}{3}\cdot P(n-1)-P(n-2)$ for $n\geq2$

How would we go about obtaining this relation from $P(n)$ given above?

Comment: Are you asking for a derivation?

Comment: If $P(n) = (1/3)^n$, isn't this simply $(1/3) P(n-1)$?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a derivation

Comment: Here's a proof: $\frac{10}{3}(\frac{1}{3})^{n-1} - (\frac{1}{3})^{n-2} = 10(\frac{1}{3})^{n} - 9(\frac{1}{3})^{n} = (\frac{1}{3})^n$

Comment: I see. Thank you! And if we are given $P(n)$, how would we come up with **any** recurrence relation?

Comment: @YinWaiTse Write $P_n=(\frac{1}{3})^n, P_{n-1}=(\frac{1}{3})^{n-1}$ then eliminate $n$ between the two to obtain a relation between $P_n$ and $P_{n-1}\,$.